# KendoUI Grid input styling in column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoui grid that is being generated with this:

```
<div id="clientsDb">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<example.OpenAccess.OBClientSetup>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.ProfileName).Width(140);
        columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Default).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.EEFinalize).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Completed).Width(110);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("OB2_ClientProfiles", "OB"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "OB"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "OB"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(obcs => obcs.SetupID))
    )
)
</div>
```

With this I cannot figure out how to style the `columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Default).Width(190);` select inputs in the column.  Its a select input dropdown but i haven't figured out how to style with `form-control` out of bootstrap. or even its own style from a temmplate within the grid code.

Answer (score 0):

`columns.Bound(obcs => obcs.Default)
    .Width(190)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "form-control "});`
You can add any attributes using the HtmlAttributes Function

Comment: that puts the class on the td and not on the select control.

Comment: Oh, my apologies I must have misunderstood the question